# JSON Submission to ASMX web service fails when a double quote is present in parameter

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am using JQuery Ajax method and Ajax to talk to a ASP.NET web service.

I have such a setup in my javascript app.

```
var parameters='Token="'+psToken+'"&ID="'+psDID+'";
$.ajax({
           type:  "GET",
           url: webMethod,
           data: parameters,
           dataType: "jsonp",
           success: function(msg) {
               XXXXX.XX(msg.X);
           },
```

As per the IIS log, I can see that all Encoding is happening right and all instances of double quotes get a %22.

The problem is that when for example psToken contains a double quote i.e " , then the web service crashes and I get a 500 error.  It doesnt even get to the point of hitting the web methods, hence I cant debug and figure out the error.

What could I be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the using of jsonp data type is not critical for you, use json dataType with following code:

```
var parameters = {
 'Token': psToken,
 'ID': psDID
};

$.ajax({
   type:  "GET",
   url: webMethod,
   data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(msg) {
       XXXXX.XX(msg.X);
   },
```